# Java - EventUserModel - why HSSFListener read all sheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have some issue about reading eventusermodel for uploading xls file:

- Why eventusermodel read all the sheet?
- How to change it?

I just want to my program read at first sheet.
Here is my example code:

```
public void processRecord(Record record)
{
    if(record.getSid()==RowRecord.sid){
        newrowrec = (RowRecord) record;
        System.out.println("new ROW NUMBER : "+ newrowrec.getRowNumber());
        System.out.println("new LAST ROW NUMBER : "+ newrowrec.getLastCol());
    }
    switch (record.getSid())
    {
        case BOFRecord.sid:
            BOFRecord bof = (BOFRecord) record;
            if (bof.getType() == bof.TYPE_WORKBOOK)
            {
                System.out.println("Encountered workbook");
                // assigned to the class level member
            } else if (bof.getType() == bof.TYPE_WORKSHEET)
            {
                System.out.println("Encountered sheet reference");
            }
            break;
        case RowRecord.sid:
            RowRecord rowrec = (RowRecord) record;
            System.out.println("Row found, first column at "
                    + rowrec.getFirstCol() + " last column at " + rowrec.getLastCol());
            break;
        case NumberRecord.sid:
            NumberRecord numrec = (NumberRecord) record;
            System.out.println("Cell found with value " + (long)numrec.getValue()
                    + " at row " + numrec.getRow() + " and column " + numrec.getColumn());
            rowlist.add(String.valueOf((long)(numrec.getValue())).toLowerCase());
            
            if(numrec.getColumn()==newrowrec.getLastCol()-1){
                System.out.println("NUMBER ROWLIST: "+ rowlist);
                extractRow(rowlist, newrowrec.getRowNumber());
                rowlist.clear();
            }
            break;

        case BlankRecord.sid:
            BlankRecord blankrec = (BlankRecord) record;
            System.out.println("BLANK VALUE at row: "+ blankrec.getRow() + " at coloumn: " + blankrec.getColumn());
            rowlist.add("null");
            break;
        case SSTRecord.sid:
            sstrec = (SSTRecord) record;
            for (int k = 0; k < sstrec.getNumUniqueStrings(); k++)
            {
                System.out.println("String table value " + k + " = " + sstrec.getString(k));
                    System.out.println("SSTRECORD ROWLIST: "+ rowlist);
            }
            break;          
        case LabelSSTRecord.sid:
            lrec = (LabelSSTRecord) record;
            rowlist.add(sstrec.getString(lrec.getSSTIndex()).toString());
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best examples of the HSSF event parsing support is in [EventBasedExcelExtractor shipped as part of Apache POI](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/EventBasedExcelExtractor.java). If you read through that, you'll see that a `BOFRecord` of type `TYPE_WORKSHEET` triggers at the start of a new sheet

So, you'll want to change your code to something like:

```
int seenSheets = 0;

....

if(record.getSid()==RowRecord.sid){
    newrowrec = (RowRecord) record;
    System.out.println("new ROW NUMBER : "+ newrowrec.getRowNumber());
    System.out.println("new LAST ROW NUMBER : "+ newrowrec.getLastCol());
}
switch (record.getSid())
{
    seenSheets++;
    if (seenSheets > 1) {
       throw new Exception("Sheet done");
....
```

And catch that exception on the outside to finish up

You might also want to use [AbortableHSSFListener](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/AbortableHSSFListener.html) to have a cleaner way to terminate when you hit the second sheet